# Why is parameter not defined?

Tags: javascript, razor

why is dtc not defined when I call @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(dtc))? I get an error that states "The name 'dtc' does not exist in the current context"

```
function createChartEncounterChart(chartid, dtc) {
    var mdl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(dtc));
...
}
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {        
        createChartEncounterChart("#chart-gender", @Model.DataByGender)
        });

Comment: Are you looking for `JSON.stringify` perhabs ? What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: no @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DataByGender)); works but I wanted to create a function I can use to create other charts too by passing in the id and data model.

Comment: ok, that's a different question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a js variable in razor view code.  The `@Html.Raw(...)` code is run on the server and `dtc` is a javascript variable that won't have any value (or be valid) until it's run in the browser.